# Кодовые точки, кодовые единицы. Тип char, String

Tags: java, строки, unicode

Как я прочитал в книге К. Хорстмана, что некоторые символы из UNICODE представляются с дополнением. Так вот меня интересует логическое представление этого. То есть, там имеется ввиду, что каждый символ в строке, к примеру "abc", может быть с дополнением, то при вызове `charAt(i)` я получу символ, если это символ с дополнением, или получу само дополнение? Если я получу само дополнение, то как мне получить посимвольно всю строку?

Comment: Приведите точную цитату из книги, а то не совсем понятно, о каком дополнении речь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309353

Comment: По индексу вы получите символ размером 16 бит, который, в случае суррогатной пары, будет представлять из себя лишь половину пары. Методами `Character.isHighSurrogate`/`Character.isLowSurrogate` можно определить, какая это половина и далее получить вторую часть суррогатной пары, вызвав `charAt(i-1)` или `charAt(i+1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые символы юникода действительно представляются в виде 2 последовательных char,т.к. char вмещает 2 байта и представляет по сути символ из UTF-16
[здесь описано как символы юникода кодируются в UTF-16,см. суррогатные пары](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

> то при вызове charAt(i) я получу символ, если это символ с
>   дополнением, или получу само дополнение?

Зависит от того при каком i вызовешь. Если подобных символов несколько,велика вероятность что получишь совсем не то что ожидал,так как сколько-то символов до этого уже было представлено в виде 2 char.
Но допустим это самый левый символ в строке, тогда при вызове `charAt(0)` и `charAt(1)`, ты получишь первый и второй char суррогатной пары
Сам символ(его Unicode код) можно получить вызвав `codePointAt(0)`,при этом `codePointAt(0)` вернет то же самое, что и `charAt(1)`

> как мне получить посимвольно всю строку?

```
"string".codePoints()
```

Comment: а можно ли получит отдельно символ, зная лишь его номер в тексте не преобразовывая всю строку в массив ?